# problem in persian alias

Tags: joomla-3.x

when i choose Persian words for the name of the articles's categories, the order of the categories in the URL gets messed up.

for example: instead of

```
`www.mysite.com/cat1/subcat2/subcat3/the-article`
```

it gets like:

```
www.mysite.com/the-article/subcat3/cat1/subcat2
```

not exactly like this, but it gets messed up. 
when i enter the alias in English, the order is ok

Persian language is a right to left language like Arabic.

any help would be appreciated
thanks

Comment: Joomla 3.8 is supposed to release on 19 September 2017 (in 3 days) and it has a new routing system. That may fix this issue you're having. If you upgrade to 3.8 and you're still having these issues then I would open a ticket/bug-report.

Comment: ok. thanks. i hope this new routing system has solved the problems :)

Comment: Any update with this question?  Did you find a resolution?

Comment: no.. I haven't found any resolutions for this problem. when rtl and ltr alphabet gets mixed, the URL gets messed up